Discoloration of object
I'm new to Blender and I'm working on a product with three separate pieces. However, when I apply materials to them, one of the objects becomes discolored. Specifically, there's a white area on the top of the bottom piece that I can't seem to fix. I've tried adjusting just the Principled BSDF shader and moving the lighting, but the issue persists. I originally modeled the parts in Fusion 360 and imported them into Blender as STL files.


Possibly inverted normals? - Go into Edit mode, select All and hit Shift-N to see if that sorts it. If not you may need to share your file here via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

As far as I understand the situation, your object looks like this because you are using a glossy shader which makes the object have a very shiny surface. What exactly is your plan, mixing two gloss shaders together in a nested system? If you can explain your thought process that might help us understand. Other than that, also check your normals. There is an overlay checkbox that lets you see the face direction. If you see reds and blues, one of your objects is inverted, proceed with the steps in the coment previous to mine if that's the case.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

My goal is to give the object a glossy plastic finish. I followed a method from a YouTube tutorial on achieving this effect. Although I tried recalculating the normals, it didn’t resolve the issue. I've also included a link to the file in the post for reference.

I think the YouTube tutorial on your material may have overcomplicated things. Try just a Diffuse BSDF with the roughness turned down, and see how you like it.

I strongly suspect that there is an internal face on the top of the bottom piece, thus making it a complete cylinder. Because it is shaded smooth, the normals are being bent into an average between the sides and the top, so the reflection of the world background renders as if it was rounded. Delete this internal face, or turn on Auto-smooth in the Normals panel of the Mesh tab of the Properties editor.
